# Change PATH for npm installs

Tags: node.js, npm, v8, gyp

Is it possible to run a pre-script before the install of a package's dependencies? I need to change the environment slightly before install of any of my package's dependencies, because my Python version is 3.3 and node-gyp (via gyp) breaks if the default Python version is not a 2.x version.

Is there a hook in this install step I could use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to be a project-level `.npmrc` with the contents

```
python=python2.7
```